# AngularJS: avoid using the 'angular' global object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm wondering if it would be a good practice to avoid using the 'angular' global object within Controllers, Services, etc.

For the sake of example, let's say we want to call the function:

```
angular.isDefined(myVar)
```

How shall we reference the 'angular' object?

Options:

1 Just use it, might get some 'variable is not defined' warning from IDEs

2 Reference the 'angular' dependency the AMD way

```
define([
        'angular'
    ], function (angular) {
        'use strict';

        return ['$log', '$filter', function ($log, $filter) {
            return {
                // ... code ...
                angular.isDefined(myVar);
            };
        }];
    }
);
```

3 Reference 'angular' the Angular way

```
module.factory('ang', function() { return angular; });

define([], function () {
        'use strict';

        return ['ang', '$log', '$filter', function (ang, $log, $filter) {
            return {
                // ... code ...
                ang.isDefined(myVar);
            };
        }];
    }
);
```

I'd go for Option 3, just wondering what would be the best way.

Comment: Depends on weather you need to test the code depending on angular or not. I prefer to never use globals directly and stick with the AMD way.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're using Angular in the first place means you don't have to worry about it being undefined. From there it's really just a static analysis problem... you want to make it clear that you're referencing a global variable.

Both solutions you've presented are good. There are a couple of other options too:

- Inject `$window` and reference `$window.angular` explicitly
- Configure your static analysis tool so it knows `angular` is defined elsewhere. You can do so with the `globals` property in `.jshintrc`.

I would probably go for a combination of `$window` and your option 3, to prevent warnings when analysing that file:

```
module.factory('ang', function($window) { return $window.angular; });
```